# How to deal with an EventHub full of bad messages?

Tags: c#, error-handling, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

**I am using EventHub -> Azure Function -> Azure SqlDatabase.**

EventHub has 32 partitions and Scaling up to 20 enabled. The function is and will always be the only one using the eventhub in the Function App. So with that I believe I gain maximum availability and throughput when needed.

Now, imagine a scenario where I have a high amount of batches going to the EventHub, but something is wrong in the messages, causing the function to not work properly and the database end up full of sql errors.

**So how do I fix the mess?**

- I have an EventHub full of 'trash'.
- I have a Function getting 'crazilly' triggered and wasting money trying to process bad messages.
- I have a DB throwing hundreds of exceptions, consuming 100% CPU and not even responding to sp_who[...]
- And I have a PoisonHub growing.

**[I don't want to have to consume all those messages getting stacked on EventHub]**

**How to start?**

1. Prevent EventHub from receiving new messages until sender is fixed
2. Stop the Function so I don't consume those messages
3. Maybe Scale Up DB, so it responds and I may kill some processes.

Fine, but now I have the whole structure stopped, which is already terrible, and an EventHub full of trash, which is going to bill useless bytes.

**Some of the 'solutions' I saw around:**

- Create a new EventHub, which is a very weird 'solution';
- Deploy an empty Azure Function to consume the trash and update Eventhub checkpoint;
- Manually change the offset on Storage for all 32 partitions.
- Simply fix the EvenHub sender and let it go...

**Well, I am not satisfied with these. Is there any better way to deal with it?**

Comment: Can't you validate the message somewhere in the process? So prevent bad messages going through?

Comment: I could try to deal with all possible errors in the Function, but I don't see a real gain on it. I would still have to check them all and waste resource.

In this scenario, the problem is already there. I want to basically skip a bunch of event hub messages without have to process them.